# Type Forwarding in .Net: Does the class forwarded need to inherit from the Type class?

Tags: c#, .net, types, forwarding

If you want to forward a class reference to another assembly with Type Forwarding, does that class need to inherit from Type?

I guess what I am really after is - What does it mean, or what is indicated, by the word "Type" in the phrase and concept of Type Forwarding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If you want to forward a class reference to another assembly with Type Forwarding, does that class need to inherit from Type?

No.

> I guess what I am really after is - What does it mean, or what is indicated, by the word "Type" in the phrase and concept of Type Forwarding.

Suppose you have a type Foo in assembly Alpha, and in your next version you realize that Foo really should have been in assembly Bravo.  You can't move the type because all your customers who have dependencies on Foo being in Alpha will be broken.

The solution is to move the type Foo into Bravo, and then ship a new version of Alpha that contains a type forwarder that tells users of Alpha "if you're looking for Foo, it's now found in Bravo". That way you don't break anyone who depends on things being the way they used to be.

> I think what I am missing here, is what the definition of "Type" is in the concept of Type Forwarding. What qualifies as a type?

The following things are type *definitions*:

- non-generic or unconstructed generic classes, structs, interfaces and delegates
- enums

The following things are type *references* (they all *refer to* another type; none of these *define* something new.)

- constructed generic classes, structs, interfaces and delegates
- arrays
- pointers
- nullables

(And there is one type that does not fall into either category, which is the return type "void".)

Of all those types, only the type definitions can be forwarded. The purpose of a type forwarder is to say "the type that used to be defined by this assembly is now defined by that assembly", so it only makes sense to forward a type *definition*. You can't forward the type `MyStruct<int>[]`; that doesn't make any sense. You can forward `MyStruct<T>`.

> what do you mean by "unconstructed generic classes? Does this mean only a generic's definition, and not a generic that has been instantiated with the type specified?

Correct.

> And can you point me to where you found the information for the "type references" and "type definitions"?

These are not concepts from the C# language specification; rather, these are concepts from the underlying Common Language Infrastructure type system. For an extensive technical look at how the CLI differs between defined and referenced types, read the ECMA 335 CLI specification, particularly looking for the sections on the metadata tables for TypeDef and TypeRef.

Comment: I just edited my question with the reason I am asking . . . lol Type Forwarding doesn't mean I can only forward types, as in value or reference types such as Int, Double, Long, etc. - it means something else. What does it mean?

Comment: @Richard: No, it means precisely that - it's basically forwarding any reference for a particular type in one assembly to a type in another assembly. Would an example help?

Comment: I think what I am missing here, is what the definition of "Type" is in the concept of Type Forwarding. What qualifies as a type?

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: Same as normal - a class, struct, enum, interface etc. See my answer for a concrete example of what Eric was talking about. (I'll go through and edit my names to match Eric's.)

Comment: Thank you both. That was what I was looking for Eric. It makes sense now. Only question I have now is, what do you mean by "unconstructed generic classes . . . etc. "? Does this mean only a generic's definition, and not a generic that has been instantiated with the type specified?

And can you point me to where you found the information for the"type references" and "type definitions"? I couldn't find anything like that anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps clearer to say you can forward `MyStruct<>` rather than `MyStruct<T>`.

Answer (score 10):

It's a slightly confusing topic, so here's a step-by-step example - now using the names from Eric's answer to help keep things consistent. We're going to start off with one library (Alpha.dll) and build an application (Test.exe) which depends on Alpha. We're then going to a type which Test.exe depends on (Foo) into a different library (Bravo.dll) without recompiling Test.exe.

1. Create the following files:

   **Foo.cs**

   ```
   using System;

   public class Foo
   {
       public static void Report()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Foo.Report");
       }
   }
   ```

   **Test.cs**

   ```
   class Test
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           Foo.Report();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build Alpha.dll:

   ```
   csc /target:library /out:Alpha.dll Foo.cs
   ```
3. Build Test.exe

   ```
   csc /r:Alpha.dll Test.cs
   ```
4. Run Test.exe - you should get the obvious output
5. Build Bravo.dll:

   ```
   csc /target:library /out:Bravo.dll Foo.cs
   ```
6. Create a new file, **Forwarding.cs**:

   ```
   using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
   [assembly:TypeForwardedTo(typeof(Foo))]
   ```
7. Recompile Alpha.dll:

   ```
   csc /r:Bravo.dll /target:library /out:Alpha.dll Forwarding.cs
   ```

   Note how we're *not* including the code for Foo in Alpha any more.
8. Run Test.exe - it will still work, despite the fact that Test.exe *asks* for a reference to Foo within Alpha.dll... the CLR simply redirects that to Bravo.dll.

   If you look in Test.exe, it will still refer to Alpha. If you look in Alpha.dll, you'll find that the code for the Foo type isn't there any more... it's only through type forwarding that it all hangs together.

Comment: BTW, thanks Jon for the great example. I was really after the "Type" part of the "Type Forwarding". I understand it now.