# Forward generic type definition

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm forwarding type definitions for our legacy support. I'm using following syntax to do so:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(NamespaceA.TypeA))]
```

problem I'm having is that I can't find correct syntax for generic type definitions (it should be possible based on [Eric Lippert's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635887/type-forwarding-in-net-does-the-class-forwarded-need-to-inherit-from-the-type) and many other places).

What I would expect as working solution is

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(NamespaceA.TypeA<T>))]
```

Any idea how write that correctly please?
Thanks.

Comment: `[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(NamespaceA.TypeA<>))]`?

Comment: Awsome. Sometimes most simple solution escapes eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(NamespaceA.TypeA<>))]
```